# thousands separators in ios pdf

Tags: c#, ios, pdf

I'm using a pdf component called pdfkit to generate a pdf. I have a decimal `206889.6` that I use like this:

```
var dec = 206889.6m;
var valueForPdf = dec.ToString("n2"); // "206 889,60"
```

This looks fine when opening the pdf, but when opening it in iOS I get following value:

> "206£889,60"

As you can see there is a `£` as thousand seperator and that doesnt look so good.

I wonder if this is something someone else has encountered before or have any ideas if this is related to the "n2" format and iOS?

*EDIT* Just realized this issue appears in adobe reader on my PC as well, when opening the PDF and mark/select the value, then the `£` appears. When not marked/selected it is a whitespace seperator

Comment: Can you try this- string valueForPdf = dec.ToString("n2").ToString(); ?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh same problem I'm afraid

Comment: It seems to be some compatibility issue with the PDF reader on iOS. Can you try opening the PDF in a browser or in some other reader in iOS?

Comment: try this `ToString("#,##0");` or `string.Format("{0:n2}", 206889.6m);`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh It looks fine with another PDF reader.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a different thousands seperator if ios? Like commas?

Comment: It seems to work if I hard code the value to `"123 456"`..

Comment: Looks like an issue in the pdf reader. PDF format should be immune to all kinda of character corruption.

Comment: @Nyerguds The same problem appears in adobe reader if I select or mark the value, then the whitespace is replace by `£`. Is there any way to put a _real_ whitespace there? It seems to be something else when formatting numbers

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was by changeing the CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator like this:

```
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

string value = amount.ToString("n2", nfi);
```

Then it works fine in safari ios aswell